# How can I uninstall a DLL from the Windows 7 GAC?

Tags: gacutil

I want to uninstall an unwanted version of a DLL which I see under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64, which I understand serves software dependent on .NET 4.0. I see the desired version of my DLL present in another GAC folder, C:\Windows\assembly, which I understand serves programs written for .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5.  If I execute "gacutil -u unwanted.dll", I get the message, "No assemblies found matching: unwanted.dll". Yet I see the DLL is there in the folder! I figure at least one of the two DLLs would have been noticed by the gacutil command and it should have been uninstalled, but no! Please help. I'd be extra grateful also if you showed me how to uninstall from the other GAC folder as well for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried giving the full path to the file?  Update your question to include a screenshot of the command prompt of exactly what you typed and the exact output/error that is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wait...never mind. Seems like I was doing it wrong. Uninstalling requires I provide gacutil the display name of my assembly, not the path! So I should have written, "gacutil -u unwanted". The display name is only "unwanted", not "unwanted.dll". I got that by executing "gacutil /l > C:\GAC_Assemblies.txt" and then searching for my DLL name inside the contents of the resulting C:\GAC_Assemblies.txt file. Interestingly, that removed both the unwanted and the desired version of my DLL, so now I'll just have to go back and reinstall the desired version and I should be good.